Symplectic linear algebra exercise
I was doing the following exercise : Let $q:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the map given by $(x_1,x_2,\xi_1,\xi_2):\mapsto (x_1\xi_1,x_2\xi_2)$. Suppose there exists a local diffeomorphism $g$ of $(\mathbb{R}^2,0)$ and a local symplectomorphism $\psi$ of $(\mathbb{R}^4,0)$ such that $q=g\circ q \circ \psi$. Then there exists a transformation $M\in GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ of the form $M=\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon_2 \end{bmatrix}$ or $M=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  \epsilon_1  \\  \epsilon_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ with $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in \{-1,1\}$ such that $Mdg=Id$.
Now my first approach was to take the differential version of $q=g\circ q\circ \psi$ and then use the resulting equation with the fact that $d\Psi$ is a symplectic matrix to get the desired result, i.e. putting it in block form $d\Psi= \begin{bmatrix}  A& B \\ C& D\end{bmatrix}$ and use the equations from $A^TD-C^TB=Id$ and $A^TC,B^TD$ are symmetric.
However I wasn't able to get the desired result? Is there another approach that might work ?
